# Groupby hours +/- some integer of additional hours

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame consisting of some columns, where the index is `datetime`, i.e. it looks something like:

```
df = 
                            col1        col2      col3        col4        col5
date                    
2021-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   55.646134   1.00      -3890.12    2437.47     4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   55.646134   2.00      -3786.65    2908.26     4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   55.646134   3.00      -3694.92    3123.63     4.716594
2021-01-01 03:00:00+01:00   55.646134   4.00      -3619.17    3251.61     4.716594
2021-01-02 00:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -743.27   1352.90     1647.35     81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1184.25  752.35      2081.33     81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1448.93  -76.22      2306.36     81.397542
2021-01-02 03:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1465.47  -1016.00    2091.12     81.397542
....
```

Now if I do something like:

```
df_grouped = list(df.groupby(df.index.hour))
```

Then I get a list of data frames where each group has either hour `00:00:00+01:00`, `01:00:00+01:00`, `02:00:00+01:00` etc. Hence 24 different groups in my case.

However, what I would like is to get them grouped by the hour, but ALSO including some integer of the previous and next hour, i.e. the resulting groups for the `df` above would instead of:

```
df_group1 =
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   55.646134   1.00     -3890.12    2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-02 00:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -743.27  1352.90     1647.35   81.397542


df_group2 =
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   55.646134   2.00    -3786.65     2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-02 01:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1184.25  752.35     2081.33   81.397542


df_group3 =
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   55.646134   3.00     -3694.92    3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-02 02:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1448.93 -76.22      2306.36   81.397542


df_group4 =
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 03:00:00+01:00   55.646134   4.00     -3619.17    3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-02 03:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1465.47 -1016.00    2091.12   81.397542
```

Become:

```
df_group1_true =
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date
2021-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   55.646134   1.00     -3890.12    2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   55.646134   2.00     -3786.65    2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-02 00:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -743.27  1352.90     1647.35   81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1184.25  752.35     2081.33   81.397542

df_group2_true = 
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   55.646134   1.00     -3890.12    2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   55.646134   2.00     -3786.65    2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   55.646134   3.00     -3694.92    3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-02 00:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -743.27  1352.90     1647.35   81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1184.25  752.35     2081.33   81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1448.93 -76.22      2306.36   81.397542

df_group3_true = 
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 01:00:00+01:00   55.646134   2.00     -3786.65    2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   55.646134   3.00     -3694.92    3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-01 03:00:00+01:00   55.646134   4.00     -3619.17    3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-02 01:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1184.25  752.35     2081.33   81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1448.93 -76.22      2306.36   81.397542
2021-01-02 03:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1465.47 -1016.00    2091.12   81.397542

df_group4_true = 
                            col1        col2     col3        col4      col5
date                    
2021-01-01 02:00:00+01:00   55.646134   3.00     -3694.92    3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-01 03:00:00+01:00   55.646134   4.00     -3619.17    3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-02 02:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1448.93 -76.22      2306.36   81.397542
2021-01-02 03:00:00+01:00   179.775434  -1465.47 -1016.00    2091.12   81.397542
```

In this example data set here there are no `23:00:00+01:00`, but obviously if you were on `00:00:00+01:00`, the previous datetime to include should be `23:00:00+01:00` and so forth.

The way I do it now is actually by doing `df_grouped = list(df.groupby(df.index.hour))` which will get me 24 data frames (one for each hour), and then something like:

```py
additional_hours = 1  # How many +/- hours I want to expand each group with.

df_list_final = [
    pd.concat(
        [df[(i + j) % 24][1] for j in range(-additional_hours, additional_hours + 1)]
    ).sort_index()
    for i in range(len(df))
]
```

And this works. However, I was wondering if there were a more elegant way of doing it with just some kind of `groupby` instead of having to concatenating a bunch of data frames all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run your code, It raises an exception, so I can be sure of the output you expect, but here is my take on your question anyway, in hope it might be helpful.

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("2021-01-01 00:00:00", 55.646134, 1.00000e00, -3890.12, 2437.47, 4.716594),
        ("2021-01-01 01:00:00", 55.646134, 2.00000e00, -3786.65, 2908.26, 4.716594),
        ("2021-01-01 02:00:00", 55.646134, 3.00000e00, -3694.92, 3123.63, 4.716594),
        ("2021-01-01 03:00:00", 55.646134, 4.00000e00, -3619.17, 3251.61, 4.716594),
        ("2021-01-02 00:00:00", 179.775434, -7.43270e02, 1352.9, 1647.35, 81.397542),
        ("2021-01-02 01:00:00", 179.775434, -1.18425e03, 752.35, 2081.33, 81.397542),
        ("2021-01-02 02:00:00", 179.775434, -1.44893e03, -76.22, 2306.36, 81.397542),
        ("2021-01-02 03:00:00", 179.775434, -1.46547e03, -1016.0, 2091.12, 81.397542),
    ],
    columns=["index", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"],
).set_index("index")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(df)
# Output
                           col1     col2     col3     col4       col5
index
2021-01-01 00:00:00   55.646134     1.00 -3890.12  2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00   55.646134     2.00 -3786.65  2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00   55.646134     3.00 -3694.92  3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-01 03:00:00   55.646134     4.00 -3619.17  3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-02 00:00:00  179.775434  -743.27  1352.90  1647.35  81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00  179.775434 -1184.25   752.35  2081.33  81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00  179.775434 -1448.93   -76.22  2306.36  81.397542
2021-01-02 03:00:00  179.775434 -1465.47 -1016.00  2091.12  81.397542
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
additional_hours = 1

# Create new index with additional values
new_index = []
for i in df.index:
    for j in range(additional_hours, 0, -1):
        new_index.append(i - pd.Timedelta(j, unit="H"))
    new_index.append(i)
    for j in range(additional_hours):
        new_index.append(i + pd.Timedelta(j + 1, unit="H"))

# Create new dataframe by merging with original df
new_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(index=new_index)
    .reset_index()
    .reset_index()
    .set_index("index")
    .merge(df, how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True, sort=False)
    .fillna(method="ffill")
    .fillna(method="bfill")
    .sort_values("level_0")
    .drop(columns="level_0")
)
```

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
                           col1     col2     col3     col4       col5
index
2020-12-31 23:00:00   55.646134     1.00 -3890.12  2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-01 00:00:00   55.646134     1.00 -3890.12  2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00   55.646134     2.00 -3786.65  2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-01 00:00:00   55.646134     1.00 -3890.12  2437.47   4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00   55.646134     2.00 -3786.65  2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00   55.646134     3.00 -3694.92  3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-01 01:00:00   55.646134     2.00 -3786.65  2908.26   4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00   55.646134     3.00 -3694.92  3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-01 03:00:00   55.646134     4.00 -3619.17  3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-01 02:00:00   55.646134     3.00 -3694.92  3123.63   4.716594
2021-01-01 03:00:00   55.646134     4.00 -3619.17  3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-01 04:00:00   55.646134     4.00 -3619.17  3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-01 23:00:00   55.646134     4.00 -3619.17  3251.61   4.716594
2021-01-02 00:00:00  179.775434  -743.27  1352.90  1647.35  81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00  179.775434 -1184.25   752.35  2081.33  81.397542
2021-01-02 00:00:00  179.775434  -743.27  1352.90  1647.35  81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00  179.775434 -1184.25   752.35  2081.33  81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00  179.775434 -1448.93   -76.22  2306.36  81.397542
2021-01-02 01:00:00  179.775434 -1184.25   752.35  2081.33  81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00  179.775434 -1448.93   -76.22  2306.36  81.397542
2021-01-02 03:00:00  179.775434 -1465.47 -1016.00  2091.12  81.397542
2021-01-02 02:00:00  179.775434 -1448.93   -76.22  2306.36  81.397542
2021-01-02 03:00:00  179.775434 -1465.47 -1016.00  2091.12  81.397542
2021-01-02 04:00:00  179.775434 -1465.47 -1016.00  2091.12  81.397542
```